# Converting a cursor to list error

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, cursor

I made a question earlier about how to swap from listview to a recyclerview. However I noticed that with my change my update and delete didn't get saved. Which from my understanding has something to do with cursors being needed to update the contents. However currenty I am stuck with the following error

```
showAdapter = new ShowsAdapter(this, shows); // the error
```

> Error:(68, 50) error: incompatible types: List cannot be converted to Cursor

```
  private List<Show> shows;
    private ShowsAdapter showAdapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private DataSource datasource;

    public static final String INTENT_DETAIL_ROW_NUMBER = "Row number";
    public static final String INTENT_DETAIL_REMINDER_TEXT = "Reminder text";
    public static final int REQUESTCODE = 2;
    public static final String EXTRA_SHOW_ID = "extraShowId";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        datasource = new DataSource(this);
        datasource.open();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.main_list);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        //recyclerView.setAdapter(showAdapter);

        updateUI();

        //registerForContextMenu(recyclerView);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.taskView);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(MainActivity.this, CreateShowActivity.class), 1);
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        shows = datasource.getAllShows();
        if (showAdapter == null) {
            showAdapter = new ShowsAdapter(this, shows); // the error
            recyclerView.setAdapter(showAdapter);
        } else {
            showAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

My Adapter:

```
  private List<Show> mShows;
    private Context mContext;

    private Cursor mShowsCursor;

    public void updateList(List<Show> newlist) {
        // Set new updated list
        mShows.clear();
        mShows.addAll(newlist);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public ShowsAdapter(Context mContext, Cursor cursor) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mShowsCursor = cursor;
    }



    @Override
    public ShowsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);

        // Return a new holder instance
        ShowsAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = new ShowsAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ShowsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        if (mShowsCursor != null && mShowsCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {

            holder.textView.setText(mShowsCursor.getString(mShowsCursor.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SHOW)));
        }

        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, EditShowActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(INTENT_DETAIL_ROW_NUMBER, position);
                intent.putExtra(INTENT_DETAIL_REMINDER_TEXT, holder.textView.getText());
                ((MainActivity) mContext).startActivityForResult(intent, REQUESTCODE);
            }
        });

        holder.mView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                mShows.remove(position);
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
                notifyItemRangeChanged(position,mShows.size());
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Well, `shows` is of type `List<Show>` whereas your constructor takes a `Cursor` as parameter.

Comment: I know, however I when I put in list<shows> it doesn't show me anything on the update call

Comment: then use [this](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b) adapter

Comment: You have to pass the `List` object and accept the `List` object in the constructor and then Set orinentation to the `LinerLayoutManager` object, before setting it to the RecyclerView. Also override `getItemCount()` in the Adapter to return the count of the List object